# Xamarin Android Access Variable in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a `broadcastReceiver` which checks an incoming intent. The incoming `intent` contains a `BluetoothDevice`. In the `BroadcastReceiver` I check weather it is the right `BluetoothDevice` or not. If yes, I want to store the name and MAC address of the device in a variable.

My problem: I can only access a `variable` which is declared as `const` in my BroadcastReceiver. How can I access a variable inside the `BroadcastReceiver`?

```
namespace firstTry3
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name")]
public class bluetoothConnectionActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Button buttonBluetoothOn;
    Button buttonConnect;
    Button buttonDissconnect;
    const string deviceName = "HC-05";                  //must be changed when bluetooth Device gets new name
    string deviceMAC = "";
    const string tag = "blueApp";
    btdeviceFoundBroadcastReceiver mBtBroadcastReciever;
```

...

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    public class btdeviceFoundBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // Do stuff here.
            string action = intent.Action;

            if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(action) && deviceMAC == "")
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
                string dName = device.Name;
                if (dName == deviceName)
                {
                    deviceMAC = device.Address;
                    Log.Info(tag, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ": bluetooth module found name: " + deviceName + " MAC: " + deviceMAC);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I can not access deviceMAC, I get the following error:

> "An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property bluetoothConnectionActivity.deviceMethod"

Comment: Where have to defined your variable is it in the activity where you register your broadcast receiver?

Comment: Did you request the permission about Location? Such as "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" or " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", you should request the location permission in android 6.0 or higher when you want to get Bluetooth info.https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes?hl=en-us#boringSSL

Comment: I have registered these permissions in the android mannifest.

Comment: the variables are defined in the activity where I register the broadcast receiver, it is all in "bluetoothConnectionActivity"

Comment: does anyone has an idea how to do that, without having to declare a variabe as static`?